# Debian 10 buster Region & Languages show only English language

Tags: debian, upgrade, settings, language

When I want to add keyboard layout I can't see any language but English.
How I can add any languages in Input Source?

[image: Region & Languages]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to click the three vertical dots option. Then, you have to click "Other" option ("Інше" in my display language). It may seem that "Other" is a caption because the search bar appears below, but it's actually an option. After clicking that option, you can either scroll or search for the language you need.